# How to create an incremental loop in PHP that print a HTML string?

Tags: php, html, string, loops, html-select

I'm having some items where one increases by 1 and the other by a specific figure, let say 275 words. So, I want to create a loop that will increase the value, which is the number of pages and the number of words in PHP.

Below, is what I want to achieve using the loop.

```
<option value="1">1 page/approx 275 words</option>
<option value="2">2 pages/approx 550 words</option>
<option value="3">3 pages/approx 825 words</option>
<option value="4">4 pages/approx 1100 words</option>
<option value="5">5 pages/approx 1375 words</option>
```

Comment: `1* 275 = 275, 2 * 275 = 550, 3 * 275 = 825` etc.

Comment: Hi Kent, can you show what you've tried so far? Stack Overflow is more about helping you find a problem in your work than it is about doing your work for you. One important thing you need to provide is: How is the page data currently stored?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php for($i=1; i<6; $i++){
    echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.' page'.($i>1 ? 's' : '').'/approx '.(275*i).' words</option>';
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
<?php

    for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) {
        $html .= '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . ' page/approx ' . 275 * $i . ' words</option>';
    }
    print($html);

?>
```

You can also add `select` open and close tags (`<select>`, `</select>`):

```
<?php
    $html = '<select>';
    for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) {
        $html .= '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . ' page/approx ' . 275 * $i . ' words</option>';
    }
    $html .= '</select>';
    print($html);
?>
```